# DCOS Minuteman VIP (with IP and port) is not reachable

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

Tried setting VIP (non name based with IP and port) as described in [the documentation](https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/networking/load-balancing-vips/#docs-article)

Also referred [the Marathon examples](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/3779).

Writing the sample json here (same as the one in above link)

```
{
  "id": "/server",
  "cmd": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80",
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "python:2.7-alpine",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "name": "http",
          "labels": {
            "VIP_0": "192.168.0.100:80"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "DOCKER"
  }
}
```

But as per the original expectation in the documentation the IP `192.168.0.100:80` should be reachable from nodes the cluster.. But apparently this doesn't work for me.. A simple Curl fails.. I need to make access this application accessible from other process which are not mesos-dns aware.

Comment: Which DC/OS version are you running? First you are referencing old 1.7 documentation. Secondly, I just tried on a 1.10 cluster and it works for me ```curl 192.168.0.100:80
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>```

Comment: We are currently in  1.8.7 release.. Could you confirm if you are able to curl from the terminal in the cluster and not inside any other marathon application..?

Comment: I could curl it from the master node, see above

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you're using would require a `USER` network, simply replace the IP address by a name:

```
  "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "name": "http",
          "labels": {
            "VIP_0": "web-app:80"
          }
        }
      ]
```

and then it should be reachable at `web-app.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:80`